# I don't understand some parts of this makefile that I have created using a tutorial

Tags: c++, makefile

Below is a makefile that I have generated by following the steps in the tutorial from [here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

I have just two mutexVsAtomics.c and mutexVsAtomics.h and they produce mutexVsAtomics.o and runMutexVsAtomic (executable).

In the tutorial it is explained that the rule starting with `%o:` should cover the case where I change the .h file then the c file should be compiled. After a bit more reading and looking at examples I notice that anything after the `:` part of a rule is a list of "dependencies" and will cause the rule to execute.

So I just added the .h (i.e. `$(DEPS)`) file in the `$(TARGET):` rule and this also now compiles if I modify the header. So I am confused about a few things.

Here is the code/makefile as it was after I completed the tutorial.... it all seems to work:

```
# Target binary filename
TARGET = runMutexVsAtomic

# Compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler Flags
CFLAGS = -std=c++11

# Include paths
PATHS = -I.

# Libraries
LIBS = -lpthread

# Include files
DEPS = mutexVsAtomics.h

#Object files
OBJ = mutexVsAtomics.o

### WHAT DOES THIS REALLY DO?... WHAT IS `$<`?###
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(PATHS) $(CFLAGS)

# Build rule - if any OBJ file or DEPS file is newer then target, then run the command line
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)    #### WHY NOT JUST ADD `$(DEPS)` HERE? ###
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) $(PATHS) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f ./*.o $(TARGET)
```

I have added comments where my questions are, but here they are explicitly:

1. In the `$(TARGET): $(OBJ)` rule why should/shouldn't I just do `$(TARGET): $(OBJ) $(DEPS)`?
2. Can you explain the rule `%.o:` in more details? e.g. Why is `%.c` there? Why is there a -c flag there? what is `$<`? and why don't we specify the `$(LIBS)`?

Comment: _"Why is there a -c flag there?"_ Refer to the documentation of `g++`. _"what is $<?"_ See e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html or https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html

Comment: Aren't most of these questions answered in the tutorial? Doesn't it explain why it's doing all these thing?

Comment: @Barmar yes, some are, some have left me confused/don't understand and some are not. So I just want someone to explain that particular rule for me in detail...

Comment: @Michael thanks for manual references... but I am after an "idiots" explanation so it is clear to me. As I said I have done further reading and due diligence, but have been left confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the $(TARGET): $(OBJ) rule why should/shouldn't I just do $(TARGET): $(OBJ) $(DEPS)?

`runMutexVsAtomic` doesn't immediately depend on the content of `mutexVsAtomics.h`, `mutexVsAtomics.o` does, unless you are making the image in one step, which you aren't here because you explicitly create an intermediate object file.

> Can you explain the rule %.o: in more details? e.g. Why is %.c there? Why is there a -c flag there? what is $

Rules starting with `%` are [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) that will match the specified pattern. The `%` in `%.c` will be substituted for whatever appears before `.o` in the target (side note: this rule looks like it should be `%.cpp` or `%.cc` since you're using `g++` and `-std=c++11`).

`-c` is a [compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) flag, it tells the compiler only to compile and not to link the final image, i.e. to make an object file.

`$<` is a make [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) that is substituted with the first prerequisite.

You don't specify `LIBS` when making the object because you aren't linking in this step.

Keep in mind make already has recipes for what you're doing, so with a few small adjustments your makefile can be shortened as follows:

```
TARGET   := mutexVsAtomics
OBJS     := mutexVsAtomics.o
CC       := g++
CPPFLAGS := -MMD
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDLIBS   := -lpthread

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(TARGET)

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I am looking for. There is still one thing a little unclear. The `$<` what does it mean by "first prerequisite`? What the the prerequisites list?  and yes it was a cpp file but I was trying to get it to work so I used .c (and changed file name) to follow the tutorial, I can change that back now :)   I will try your simpler looking suggestion as well

Comment: @code_fodder the prerequisites are whatever appears after the `:` in a rule.

Comment: ahhh... so its the .c file in this case, got it, thanks!

Comment: Ok one more thing, I tried your example. At first it did not work, but I figured that I needed to change my filename to .cpp so make knows its c++/g++. This worked - i.e. built and the .o file was produced. However the target file was not created. What mods need to be made to do this? - I really don't understand this example, but I'l be happy to get it working and then go off and read about these make recipes : )

Comment: You probably didn't use the example exactly as I posted, it's important that the final target's name is identical to one of the object files (minus the `.o` of course) if you want to use make's built in recipe for executables, I'm guessing `TARGET` in your makefile is still `runMutexVsAtomic`.

Comment: Oh I see, yes I did not understand that was required. I also had to either add the line `CC   := g++` or add `-lstdc++` to the LDLIBS. For some reason it seemed to still be using gcc not g++. Having said that, it seems to work now :)

Comment: @code_fodder Good catch! I didn't test with the library, the built-in recipe for linking uses `CC` which by default will be `cc`, which probably won't link in the c++ library depending on your setup.

Comment: yeah I thought it might be something like that - I had been through that loop already, but its only a minor one ; )   thanks very much for your help I think I am good to go : )